# How to convert canvas mouse coordinates in custom XY values and mark the cell

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas element with overlay-grid and store the mouse coordinates in a field by click event.

But now i need a custom conversion in custom axis-values and mark the clicked cell. (example cell D4)

[image]

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400" style="background: url(''); background-size: cover;" onclick="storeGuess(event)"></canvas>

<input id="coords_c" name="coords_c" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($position->coords_c, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
```

Javascript:

```
    var bw = 480;
    var bh = 400;
    var p = 0;
    var cw = bw + (p*2) + 0;
    var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawBoard(){
    for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 40) {
        context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
        context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
    }

    for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += 20) {
        context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
        context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    }

    drawBoard();

    var canvasSetup = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvasSetup.getContext("2d");
    guessX = 0; 
    guessY = 0; 
    function storeGuess(event) {
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        guessX = x;
        guessY = y;

        var tipWidth=35;
            var tipHeight=22;
            var tipRow;
            var tipCol;

        $('#coords_c').val( + guessX + "/" + guessY);
        console.log("x coords: " + guessX + ", y coords: " + guessY);
    }
```

Comment: Please progress this page to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: I'm saving all the cells into the cells array. Then on click I detect the cell where the click event happened. I paint this cell red. Here you may decide to save the clicked cell index (pos) in an other array.

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
// the width and the height of the canvas
const cw = canvas.width =  480;
const ch = canvas.height = 400;
// the width and the height of every cell
let rw = 40;
let rh = 20;
// the number of cells per row
let w = cw / rw;
// the number of cells per column
let h = ch / rh;
// the mouse position
let m = {};
// the array of cells
let cells = [];

// the canvas context
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");


// a function to draw a cell
function drawCell(o,fill){
  let fillcolor = fill ? fill : "white";
  context.fillStyle = fillcolor;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(o.x,o.y);
  context.lineTo(o.x+rw, o.y);
  context.lineTo(o.x+rw, o.y+rh);
  context.lineTo(o.x, o.y+rh);
  context.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
  context.closePath()
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}


// a function to draw the board
function drawBoard(){
  for (var y = 0; y < ch; y += rh) {
    for (var x = 0; x < cw; x += rw) {
      let o = {x:x,y:y}
      //draw the cell and pust the coords of the cell onto the cells array
      drawCell(o);
      cells.push(o)
    }
  }
}

drawBoard();


canvas.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
  // get the mouse position
  m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
  // get the index of the clicked cell
  let pos = (~~(m.y / rh))* w + ~~(m.x / rw);
  // fill the clicked cell
  drawCell(cells[pos],"red")
  // here you can store the guess in an aray if this is what you need
})


    
// a function to get the mouse position    
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return { 
 x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
 y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> Do you have any idea how to clear all the already marked cells before select another one but still keep the dashboard? So that only one cell is marked every time.

In this case you need to clear the context, and redraw the grid before filling the clicked cell:

```js
// the width and the height of the canvas
const cw = canvas.width =  480;
const ch = canvas.height = 400;
// the width and the height of every cell
let rw = 40;
let rh = 20;
// the number of cells per row
let w = cw / rw;
// the number of cells per column
let h = ch / rh;
// the mouse position
let m = {};
// the array of cells
let cells = [];

// the canvas context
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");


// a function to draw a cell
function drawCell(o,fill){
  let fillcolor = fill ? fill : "white";
  context.fillStyle = fillcolor;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(o.x,o.y);
  context.lineTo(o.x+rw, o.y);
  context.lineTo(o.x+rw, o.y+rh);
  context.lineTo(o.x, o.y+rh);
  context.lineTo(o.x, o.y);
  context.closePath()
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}


// a function to draw the board
function drawBoard(){
  for (var y = 0; y < ch; y += rh) {
    for (var x = 0; x < cw; x += rw) {
      let o = {x:x,y:y}
      //draw the cell and pust the coords of the cell onto the cells array
      drawCell(o);
      cells.push(o)
    }
  }
}

drawBoard();


canvas.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
  // get the mouse position
  m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
  // get the index of the clicked cell
  let pos = (~~(m.y / rh))* w + ~~(m.x / rw);
  // clear the context
  context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  // draw the board
  drawBoard()
  // fill the clicked cell
  drawCell(cells[pos],"red")
  // here you can store the guess in an aray if this is what you need
})


    
// a function to get the mouse position    
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return { 
 x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
 y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea how to clear all the already marked cells before select another one but still keep the dashboard? So that only one cell is marked every time. clearRect?